# Timeframes in pinescript

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, indicator, pine-script-v4

I am trying to have my indicator plot zones based on various timeframes, however when i can seem to figure out how to get the timeframe function to work.

```
`// Timeframes to check
var timeFrame30 = 30
var timeFrame45 = 45
var timeFrame60 = 60
var timeFrame120 = 120
var timeFrame180 = 180
var timeFrame240 = 240
var timeFrame1440 = 1440
var timeFrame10080 = 10080
var timeFrame43200 = 43200

// Iterate through timeframes
for time_frame in [timeFrame30, timeFrame45, timeFrame60, timeFrame120, timeFrame180, timeFrame240, timeFrame1440, timeFrame10080, timeFrame43200]:
    demand_zones = []
    supply_zones = []`
```

I get the error 'time_frame' is not a valid type keyword in variable declaration and if i use

```
timeframes = [timeFrame30, timeFrame45, timeFrame60, timeFrame120, timeFrame180, timeFrame240, timeFrame1440, timeFrame10080, timeFrame43200]
```

i get a syntax error "["

Answer (score 0):

Timeframes don't work that way.

If you want to get data from different timeframes, you should use the [security()](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/essential/Context_switching_the_security_function.html) function.

```
//@version=5
indicator("Example security", overlay=true)
close_15 = security(syminfo.tickerid, "15", close)
plot(close_15)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use array.from:

```
timeframes = array.from(timeFrame30, timeFrame45)
```